# Laravel pagination breaks if fetching total count of data after getting the result set. Any idea why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $params = $request->except('_token');

        $profiles = Profile::filter($params);

        $resultsSet = [
            "result_count" => $profiles->count(),
            "data" => $profiles->skip( ($params['page_number'] - 1) * $params['page_size'] )->take($params['page_size'])->get()
        ];

        return json_encode($resultsSet);
    }
```

This is working. However, as soon as I switch the order of the `$resultSets` the resulting `count()` value starts giving me 0 when the page_number is more than 1. Switched code for `$resultsSet` is:

```
$resultsSet = [
            "data" => $profiles->skip( ($params['page_number'] - 1) * $params['page_size'] )->take($params['page_size'])->get(),
            "result_count" => $profiles->count()
        ];
```

Why is this happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `$profiles` data get manipulated after that `skip` operation on it, 
What you can do is to clone the variable and use it like this to make your count unaffected.

```
    $profiles = Profile::filter($params);
    $temp = clone $profiles  // This is will make exact copy of your $profile variable

    $resultsSet = [
        "result_count" => $temp->count(),
        "data" => $profiles->skip( ($params['page_number'] - 1) * $params['page_size'] )->take($params['page_size'])->get()
    ];
```

Now even if you reverse the order the count will remain unaffected

```
$resultsSet = [
            "data" => $profiles->skip( ($params['page_number'] - 1) * $params['page_size'] )->take($params['page_size'])->get(),
            "result_count" => $temp->count(),
        ];
```

I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer does take me one step further but it still doesn't explain why the count is now 0.

Comment: I told you that $profiles is manipulated if it is put first which affects the count of $profiles if it is placed after @SaketJain

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But why is it being 0? I mean it should just get reduced by the number of profiles I'm skipping (that's what I'd expect usual behavior to be)

Comment: @SaketJain  You must verify your query and see if it is doing something unexpected